# Comparing file timestamps

Tags: python, timestamp

I want to compare two files from two different folders based on when they were created.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, time, datetime 
f1 = "/home/source/file1.py"
f2 = "/home/backup3/file1.py"
os.path.getatime(f1)
print time.ctime(os.path.getatime(f1))
print time.ctime(os.path.getatime(f2))
```

The files were created at different times, but I get the same time and date as output; why? I would like to compare the timestamps of these two files so that whenever `source/file1.py` is changed we make a new copy of it in `backup3`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use the `os.path.getmtime(path)` or the `os.path.getctime(path)` methods for getting the last modification or creation timestamp, respectively.

From the docs, `os.path.getatime(path)` returns the time of last access of path. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getatime